# How can I use date type using map function in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, indexing, map-function

I've just started studying React.

I'm using map function to use data.

Here's my code.

```
{dailynoteList.map((val) => {
      return (
        <div key={val.index} className="dailybox">


          //<div className="valSubject"> 
            //<div className="subjectText">{val.subject}</div>  
          //</div>

          <div className="contentDate">
            <div className="valDate">{val.date}</div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      )
    })}
```

And the result of "{val.date}" is like this.

[image]

I want to use only month and date like "8/8" or "August 8".

How can I use {val.date}?

Comment: parse the date. `{new Date(val.date)}`, then you can format it however you like. Simple example: `<div className="valDate">{new Date(val.date).toDateString()}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

install

`npm install moment --save`

import to your component

`import moment from 'moment'`

change

```
<div className="valDate">{new Date(val.date).toDateString()}</div>
```

to

```
<div className="valDate">{moment(val.date).format('LL')}</div>
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use moment anymore as it's deprecated .

Comment: You should use dayjs instead

Comment: @Shyam OK, Thanks.

Comment: @VũHuyHoàng OK, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just utilize the `Date` constructor and the method `toDateString` to format it.

```
<div className="valDate">{new Date(val.date).toDateString()}</div>
```

You may also use package `moment` for this and it provides more formatting, but the library is quite heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) to format day.

```
{dayjs(val.date).format("M/D")} // return 8/8

{dayjs(val.date).format("MM/DD")} // return 08/08

{dayjs(val.date).format("MMMM D")} // return August 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right question, it should be
`How to get year/month/day from a date object?`

anyway JS only
you can

```js
new Date(val.date).toLocaleDateString()
// thats will return "8/8/2021"

// or you can

new Date(val.date).toLocaleDateString().slice(0,3)
// thats will return 8/8
```

Im suggestion that you play a bit with Date constructor, and read about it
[JavaScript Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)